# Issues with dropdown navigation menu using jquery in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am having some problems with the jquery drop down navigation menu , its working fine with all the browsers apart from IE 7,8.
Below I have attached the 2 images and have included the css and markup for it , Any assistance will be highly appreciated, regards

Dropdown Navigation image display with all other browsers(required output)
[image]
Dropdown Navigation image display with IE (submenu is starting below company , it should start just below the products)
[image]
CSS:

```
.hide {
display:none;
  }
 .nave {
width:960px;
padding:10px 0px 0px 10px;
margin:0 auto;
  }
  .quiklinks
 {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
height: 45px;
font-family: Tahoma, Arial;
font-size: 12px;
text-align: center;
clear: both;
float: left;
width: 960px;
background: url('../Images/navebg.png') no-repeat left top;
}
.quiklinks ul {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
 }
.quiklinks li
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
display: block;
background: url('../Images/divider.png') no-repeat left top;
height: 45px;
float: left;
 }
.quiklinks li a {
display:block;
height:41px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ebeaea;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:35px;
padding:2px 20px 0px 20px;
float:left;
     }
  .quiklinks li a:hover {
display:block;
height:41px;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:35px;
padding:2px 20px 0px 20px;
float:left;
    }
     /*style the sub menu*/

   .quiklinks .ul-links li ul
 {
position:absolute;
visibility: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 100;
top: 52px;
 }

 .quiklinks .ul-links li ul li
{
display: inline;
height: 35px;
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: none !important;
}

 .quiklinks .ul-links li ul li a:link, .quiklinks .ul-links li ul li a:visited
{
 background: url('../Images/nav-ul-li.png') repeat-x left top;
width: 100px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 12px;
color: #FFFFFF;
height: 35px;
font-weight: bold;
 }

.quiklinks .ul-links li ul li a:hover
{
background: url('../Images/nav-ul-li-hover.png') repeat-x 0px 0px;
}
```

Html Markup:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.ul-links > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
         $('.ul-links > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);

         function openSubMenu() {
             $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');
         };

         function closeSubMenu() {
             $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');
         };

     });
  </script>
  <div class="nave">
<div class="quiklinks">

  <ul class="ul-links">

  <li><a href="/" id="quiklinks_01">Home</a><span class="hide">Home</span></li>

 <li><a href="#" rel="nofollow" id="quiklinks_02">News</a><span class="hide">About us</span></li>

   <li><a href="/business-customers.aspx" rel="nofollow" id="quiklinks_03">Products</a><span   class="hide">Business Customers</span></li>

   <li><a href="/security.aspx" rel="nofollow" id="quiklinks_04">Latest Products</a><span class="hide">Security</span>

    <ul>
                <li>
                     <a href="/products/carpets.aspx" >Product1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                     <a href="/products/laminates.aspx" >Product2</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                     <a href="/products/vinyls.aspx" >Product3</a>
                </li>



            </ul>


  </li>

  <li><a href="/shippingInfo.aspx" rel="nofollow" id="quiklinks_06">Company</a><span class="hide">Delivery Information</span></li>

  <li><a href="/articles.aspx" id="quiklinks_09">Ordering</a><span class="hide">Articles & Reviews</span></li>

    <li><a href="/help.aspx" rel="nofollow" id="quiklinks_08">Contact</a><span class="hide">Help</span></li>

     <li><a href="/contactus.aspx" rel="nofollow" id="quiklinks_07">Links</a><span class="hide">Contact Us</span></li>


      </ul>
```

Comment: You did not say what is problem in IE 7 and 8 (how it renders, what does not work). Pictures referenced in css and openSubMenu and closeSubMenu javascript functions are not included so nobody can reproduce that menu to check what is about.

Comment: well if you see the attached pictures , the submenu behaviour in IE is a bit different as compared to other browsers, I want the submenu to start exactly below the latest products but in IE its starting from company

Comment: Try giving `.quiklinks .ul-links li ul` an attribute of `left:0;`

Comment: left 0 start from the starting of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mr A; as ricky said give `left:0;` to your `.quiklinks .ul-links li ul` & give [position:relative](http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) to it's parent

css:

```
.quiklinks .ul-links li ul{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top: 52px;
}
.quiklinks .ul-links li{
     position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now the submenu starts just below the home button

Comment: .quiklinks .ul-links li is the parent of .quiklinks .ul-links li ul check the css for reference